# Include fonts and assets when building a Vue component library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, build, vuejs2

Right now I'm using [`vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib [entry]`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library) to build Vue as a component library to use in other projects.

However, it only generates four files which are:

```
dist/myLib.umd.min.js 
dist/myLib.umd.js
dist/myLib.common.js
dist/myLib.css
```

It doesn't have any `assets/` folder which I store fonts in the `dist/` folder.

What parameters or configurations do I have to make to be able to embed the fonts with the library?

Comment: What way are you including images in your application?
Are you importing them? Are you using url-loader/file-loader?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

Im having the same issue. It would be helpful if i get some insight on how to bundle libary with fonts and images

Answer (score 1):

Well, what is working for me is setting the following config to my 'vue.config.js'file:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  assetsDir: './',
  css: {
    extract: false,
    sourceMap: true,
  }
})
```

That makes the CSS (with the @font-face) go to the 'XXXX.common.js', in my case, the font file was exported to '/dist/fonts'

Comment: Another thing that is NOT beautiful at ALL, but WORKS!! Is create a component with your CSS (tokens for colors, generic classes, etc.) and fonts! After that, you can use that component in your "REAL" components. 
In the end, when you build your lib and import it in your project, every thing will be working ;)